# Custom Downloadable Product

Tags: orders, downloadable

Need help on one issue we are facing :

We want to use a downloadable product (ie digital product) but along with the product file, we also want to take input from users on Product details page.

For this, we can create the TextArea or Upload File options on the product detail page. Now the final output which users can download will not be the file that was uploaded for Product by admin but a custom file depending on the user inputs provided on the Product Details page and this will vary for each customer.

On order submission, the custom product file will be created offline and uploaded back to My Order page from where the user can download it. How can we achieve this using Magento?

Comment: so the thing you want is, when the user buys the downloadable product customer won't get the link to download the file inputted in downloadable product instead once the order is placed, admin will create a custom file based on the information inputted by the customer and will upload it to the website which can be downloaded by the user?

Comment: Yes exactly. User should be able to download it from MyOrder page.

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion in comment, it is not a standard functionality of Community Version of Magento. You will have to create a custom extension to implement it. Moreover, creating a custom extension will be much time consuming.

I would suggest you to use some of the third party extension available. The link of some of the extensions are:

> 1)
>   http://top-magento-extensions.com/custom-downloads-extension-to-extend-magento-downloadable-product.html
>
> 2) https://technology.pillwax.com/software/downloadplus-for-magento.html

**Please Note: I am in no way associated with the developer of the extension or the extension company. I take no guarantee of the product or services they provide**

Comment: Thanks Dexter for your help. Is there any extensions available for lesser cost?

Comment: I am not sure about it. you can try searching internet and post it over here if you find one.